# In Kimi no Na Wa., how long does the comet fragment take to reach Itomori Town?

Tags: your-name

In Kimi no Na Wa, Mitsuha is able to save everyone in the town even as the comet fragments were falling. So I'd like to ask, just how long would the comet fragment take to fall, in a timeframe that still allows everyone to reach the High School before the comet strikes?

Comment: Since it's a happy ending *anime*, the comet will wait for everyone to safely reach the school. Then it'll fall. As for the actual answer to your question, I don't know and would like to know as well..

Comment: Haha! I suppose. Let's see if anyone has an answer other than yours, 'cause it'll be interesting.

Comment: This is bugging me too - in the original timeline, the fragment seems to have impacted Itomori almost immediately (within a few minutes, say) after it split off. But in the revised timeline, it must have been at least an hour between the split (Mitsuha is still running towards city hall at this point) until impact (by which point evacuation would've been complete).

Comment: I agree with @Nightshade, it's an anime, don't think too much! :P

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think the comet's fragment has gone through a full orbit around the Earth, because it is unlikely that it has diverted so much from the original comet trajectory (which is tangential to Earth) to fall almost perpendicularly, since the break was above Japan and the fragment also fell in Japan
[image: Comet fragment trajectory]

So it is likely that more than an hour has passed between the break and the impact.

By the way, I'm not an aerospace engineer, maybe my reasoning does not make sense ^^

Answer (score -1):

It reached its perigee at 7:50. At 8:52 it impacted. In the light novel, it was written that everyone stood in awe until it was to late.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or page number for the source?